# Eclipse shows � character instead of § on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, encoding

Upon opening `.java` files created in Windows in Eclipse, my Macbook converts what were `§` characters to `�`. I've tried changing the text encoding to `UTF-8` in `General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding`. Opening the `.java` files in other editors such as Sublime Text seems to work fine. Eclipse plugins are `Saros` and `Aptana`.

Comment: Does the font that you are using support §?

Comment: Yes, I can type §s. I can manually replace all � with § but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you share the .java file?

Comment: Fixed, I had to change the encoding to what it was on my Windows Eclipse - Cp1252. Never heard of it, but that seems to work while UTF-8 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had to change the encoding to what it was on my Windows Eclipse - Cp1252. Never heard of it, but that seems to work while UTF-8 doesn't.